# Force an Action Listener to happen?

Tags: java, swing, awt

How do you force an action listener to do an action when you first start up the program? For my program, I have to literally click on the drop down list and select a name to trigger an action listener. How would I force this selection to happen right away as soon as I start up the program?

EDIT:

I am using `JComboBox` components, just to be sure there's an understanding here.

Comment: could you clarify about the context in which you require this?

Comment: Why do you have to use an ActionListener?
How about you write a method that contains the stuff the ActionListener should do, and call it from the ActionListener? Then you can also call the method at startup, independent of the Listener?

Comment: @Blip, So, let's just say the first name on the list is Bob. And there's another text field after Bob, but it is blank until an action listener from Bob's JComboBox is triggered. I want that action listener triggered at the start of the program instead of me having to manually click on the drop down menu and select Bob. If that makes any sense. :/

Comment: Just set the textfield to the required text using setText. e.g. JTextField.setText("bob");

Comment: why don't you fill up the text field with the initial value when you initialise the textbox and then let action listener do its job when your user selects a new value?

Comment: @KyalBond, But that's hardcoding. I'm retrieving data from a database, so if I change that person's last name in the database, it'll be different than what is in the database.

Comment: Then just retrieve the information you need, as you will be calling that information to use from somewhere?

Comment: does your action listener retrieve the data for the selected item from the database?

Comment: Yes, I guess. But, that's not the point. I guess I'll do it this way then.

Answer (score 0):

Where your action listener calls the code you wish to execute, put it into a method and then just call it as soon as you start up the program.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is looking for this solution, I found it. Simply put this line of code AFTER your action listeners:

```
combobox.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Where `combobox` is the name of your JComboBox component.